# How can I open a directory by its name?

Tags: python, directory, filesystems

I am writing a program that prompts for the name of the directory and then saves all the file names in a list. How can I get a path to a specific directory obly knowing its name?

I tried `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` but it would only show me my current dir, where the file with the program is, not the searchable dir.

Comment: Try replacing the `os.path.realpath(__file__)` with the directory name entered by the user.

Answer (score 1):

`__file__` is a special variable in python that includes the current file's path. If understand your question correctly, then all you need is to pass the variable where you have stored user input from the prompt in place of `__file__`. So you will have something like:

```
print("what dir do you want to search?")
searchable_dir = input()
print(
    "You selected " +
    os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath( searchable_dir ))
)
```

This is good as a learning exercise, but note that to get a list of files in a directory the preferred method would be to use [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir).

Comment: Thank you so much! The only thing is, I wanted to look for any directory in my computer (say I am in directory #1 and my program is in directory #1. I wanted to look through directory #2 and find files there)

Comment: `searchable_dir` here is a string that can be any directory on your computer. Maybe you should test something like this out in the python console: `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath( "/home/username/" ))` to get a feel for it.